# CSS ordered list - style the number, when li contains multiple lines, maintaining indentation

Tags: html, css

Variants of this question have been asked and answered, but I can't find an answer to this specific question...

I would like to style the number in each `li` item in my `ol`, ***given*** that each `li` may span multiple lines, in a way that ***maintains the indentation.***

For example - here is a simple, un-styled example:

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ol>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

This produces the following result - note the proper indentation of multiple lines:

[image]

I've tried styling the numbers using `li:before`:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: li;
}
li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(li) '.';
  width: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ol>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Now, I can easily style the numbers, but the indentation on multiple lines is lost:

[image]

So, how can I style the numbers, ***and*** maintain proper indentation?

Comment: Try adding `list-style:none; display:table-row;` to your `li` CSS and then `display:table-cell;` to the `:before` [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deakinja/dgLue218/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also update the `display:` to use the `table` values.

The `table-row` value makes the element act like a `<tr>` and the `table-cell` makes the element act like a `<td>` ensuring that the different parts of the list stay aligned.

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: li;
  display:table-row;
  
}
li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(li) '.';
  width: 1.2em;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ol>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
    <li>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</li>
    <li>blah</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this css.

```
li {
  counter-increment: li;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
li:before {
  margin-right: 10px;
  content: counter(li) '.';
  width: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: -30px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make some space on the left side of the element by padding it, remove the `:before` element from the content flow with `position: absolute`, and position it in the space created by the padding.

```
ol {
  counter-reset: li;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  counter-increment: li;
  /* Anchor all :before elements to their respective li */
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 1em;
}
li:before {
  content: counter(li) '.';
  width: 1.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind introducing another element, you can just wrap the text in a span.

```css
li {
  color: red;
}
li span {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px;">
  <ol>
    <li><span>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</span></li>
    <li><span>blah</span></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```